# How to bind a TextBox on a Formregion to a custom property?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

C#, VSTO, Outlook 2016

I've created a Outlook Formregion with a TextBox.
I want to bind the TextBox control to a custom property.

I've found the SetControlItemProperty method:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.formregion.setcontrolitemproperty

Is there a similar method in c# and how can I use this method
and where should this method be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of managed add-ins you need to set the property programmatically. There are no automatic bindings in case of VSTO add-ins.

You can read a property value at runtime using any standard Outlook mechanisms like `UserProperties` or `CustomProperties` and set the `Text` property of your control programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Ah ok, thank you Eugene.

So the following is not possible:

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using MSForms = Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms;

namespace myHumbleAddin
{
  partial class frmDataTable
  {
    private void frmDataTable_FormRegionShowing(object s, EventArgs e) {
      Outlook.FormRegion mRegion = this.OutlookFormRegion;
      mRegion.SetControlItemProperty(mRegion.Form.mTextBox, "userField");
    }
  }
}
```

BUT the intellisense feature shows the SetControlItemProperty method.
Is there no chance to use this?

[Intellisense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TH4r4.png)

Comment: Do you have the property value set correctly for the text box control in that case?

Comment: The property name part in the SetControlItemProperty call is correct. The mTextbox control also. But I'm getting a Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: System.__ComObject has no definition of mTextBox??!? And no, no typos!

Comment: That's why I recommended setting properties programmatically on your own. I suppose that is for compatibility with unmanaged form regions designed in Outlook, not in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Würg, thank you Eugene.
Life could be so easy if Micro'!%-&%"? ...

My solution so far (only for appointments):

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace myHumbleAddin
{
  partial class frmDataTable
  {
    private void frmDataTable_FormRegionShowing(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
      Outlook.FormRegion currentRegion = this.OutlookFormRegion;
      Outlook.AppointmentItem currentItem = OutlookItem as Outlook.AppointmentItem;

      // Bind a control on the form to a UserPropertyField
      void bindControl (System.Windows.Forms.Control control, string customProperty) {

        string _value = currentItem.UserProperties[customProperty].Value.ToString();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_value)) {
          control.Text = _value;
        }
      }

      if ( (currentItem != null) && (currentItem is Outlook.AppointmentItem) ) { 
        bindControl(tbBez, "Bezeichnung");
      }
    }

    private void frmDataTable_FormRegionClosed(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
      Outlook.AppointmentItem currentItem = OutlookItem as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
      
      void setControlContents(System.Windows.Forms.Control control, string customProperty) {

        string _value = currentItem.UserProperties[customProperty].Value.ToString();

        if (control.Text.Length != 0 && control.Text != _value) {
          currentItem.UserProperties[customProperty].Value = control.Text;
        }
      }

      setControlContents(tbBez, "Bezeichnung");
    }
  }
}
```

Any improvements are appreciated since I'm a beginner in this Outlook world.